# How can I multiply unaligned numpy matrices in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I've got two numpy matrices: the first, `indata` has a shape of `(2, 0)`. The second (`self.Ws[0]` in my code) has a shape of `(100, 0)`.

Is it possible to multiply these matrices by each other?

```
def Evaluate(self, indata):
    sum = np.dot(self.Ws[0], indata) + self.bs[0]
    self.As[0] = self.sigmoid(sum)
    for i in range(1, len(self.numLayers)):
        sum = np.dot(self.Ws[i], self.As[i-1] + self.bs[i])
        self.As[i] = self.softmax(sum)
    return self.As[len(self.numLayers)-1]
```

The error I'm getting when running this code is the following:

```
File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Assignment4PartC/Program.py", line 28, in main
    NN.Train(10000, 0.1)
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\Assignment4PartC\Network.py", line 53, in Train
    self.Evaluate(self.X[i])
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\Assignment4PartC\Network.py", line 38, in Evaluate
    sum = np.dot(self.Ws[0], indata) + self.bs[0]
ValueError: shapes (100,) and (2,) not aligned: 100 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Hopefully somebody can help me out with this -- any help is appreciated! If anyone needs more granular information about what I'm running, just let me know and I'll update my post.

Comment: Hey Gideok, I don't know that it's possible to multiply matrices of these shapes by one another. What output are you expecting?

Comment: `dot` product for 2 1d array is the inner product. The 2 arrays have to match in size.

Comment: Is there any way to convert (100, ) -> (100, 1) ?

Comment: You can simply use `arr.reshape((-1, 1))` to have your array reshaped as (N, 1) where N is the shape of the array. I am not sure though that what you are doing is going to be mathematically sound.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as shape `(N, 0)` for an array unless the array is empty. What you have is probably of shape `(2,)` and `(100,)`. One way of multiplying these objects is:

```
np.dot(self.Ws[0].reshape((-1, 1)), indata.reshape((1, -1)))
```

This is going to give you a `(100, 2)` array.
Whether this is what you want to get from a mathematical perspective it is really hard to say.

Comment: Sure it's possible to have a (100,0) shape array. But the error says `Ws[i]` is shape (100,). So `Ws` is probably (n,100).  But I agree that the intention of the `dot` is unclear.

Comment: It is possible, but only for truly empty arrays (i.e. no elements whatsoever). It may be that I lack imagination, but I do not see a use case for an empty array with some non-empty shape.